# Nemo 'File Management preferences' has no exit

Tags: files, nemo, preferences

Ubuntu 20.04.1
Cinnamon desktop recently installed.

Working with files and folders in Nemo 4.4.2 and when I finish, I can't find a way to close the Nemo 'File Management preferences'?

It floats on top of open file windows so it's annoying. Only way I've been able to close is to reboot. There was one time it just disappeared after messing around but I couldn't tell what did it. ESC doesn't help. There's no X in the upper right corner.

Any ideas? I have found that closing Nemo and waiting 30 seconds or so the preferences window closes but I'm usually working on files and don't want to do that...

Comment: Is the 'Nautilus' in your headline an error?

Comment: Err, I don't know. I was searching around on my computer for the proper names for things and when I searched for files, "Files (Nautilus)" showed up. BUT I didn't click on it. I see now, after searching, that it is different then the Nemo file manager. I just assumed Nemo was a sub name or something of Nautilus. Guess not. I never use Nautilus.

Comment: Nautilus is the default file manager for Ubuntu. When you installed Cinnamon, it came with its own file manager. The default file manager for Cinnamon is Nemo. Sadly, I can't replicate your problem. I do have a Cinnamon DE computer, but it's Mint's Debian edition and it works just fine. Anyhow, you've seemingly discovered a bug and should probably [report it](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs). Is it the only application that doesn't have the X in the corner to close it?

Comment: Just checked several apps, in the 'A's and they all have X. It would take far too long to check them all this AM and I have a long trip today so I'll check the rest of the alphabet when I get back later this afternoon. However, I've been using Cinnamon for a while now (possibly a week?) and don't recall any others w/o the X.

Comment: It sounds like a bug, from your description. That's generally off-topic here and should be reported properly when you get time. It's not a long process to report it.

Comment: Who do I report it too? Ubuntu, Cinnamon, Nemo? Is there a link to their bug reporter or is it something built into the desktop? Oh, wow, just discovered that version 4.4.2 that I'm using is way back...current version is 4.6.5-1. Guess I need to update. I installed Cinnamon from Term and did all the updating there, seems it doesn't update all the packages.

Comment: It only updates what is in the repo and Cinnamon isn't really an Ubuntu priority at this time. The rumor mill says that Ubuntu Cinnamon may become an official Ubuntu flavor in the future. Anyhow, see my second comment in this exchange. There's a link in that comment has all the directions for filing a bug. In this case, I'd file it against Nemo. Nemo would be the most appropriate package to file it under.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click where the X should be and a menu should come up where you can hit close